# Why can't i access this object in GCD

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

```
Server* mImpl;


void receiveImage()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [mImpl function];
        });
        return;
}
```

I have this peice of code above. For some reason, whenever this code is wrapped in a GCD as such, I get an error saying an `-[UIWindowLayer function]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives you your answer.

The problem is that "`mImpl` is defined as a UIWindowLayer and there is no such thing as "`function`" on a UIWindowLayer object.

And in fact, I don't even thing UIWindowLayer is a public Apple / iOS framework thing.  You probably need to figure out why your "`Server`" is being declared in that function to be a UIWindowLayer.  Did you define or set it up properly before "`receiveImage`" gets called?

Comment: I have no idea why its a UIWindowLayer. It's just an NSObject